# jpanel inside jscroll inside jpanel inside jscroll doesnt get scrollable

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

i have a jscroll (scroll) with a jpanel inside(main panel) and inside main panel i want to add scrollable jpanels(panel_12). So i add every panel_12 inside a new jscroll(scroll_12) and i add scroll_12 into main_panel. The problem is panel_12 doesnt get scrollable...

Here is my code:

```
    panel_12.setPreferredSize(thePanelDimension);

    panel_12.setLayout(null);
    JScrollPane scroll_12 = new JScrollPane(panel_12, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    scroll_12.setPreferredSize(thePanelDimension);
    scroll_12.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    scroll_12.setViewportView(panel_12);        

    main_panel.add(scroll_12);
```

Note: main_panel inside scroll works fine with that code

```
    JPanel main_panel = new JPanel();

    GridLayout gd_main_panel = new GridLayout();
    gd_main_panel.setVgap(-1);
    gd_main_panel.setHgap(-1);
    main_panel.setLayout(gd_main_panel);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(main_panel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scroll.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    scroll.setBounds(272, 115, 1022, 560);
    contentPane.add(scroll);
```

Thank you very much

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: `I would like to see if anyone else has to propose another solution...` - Don't use a null layout. Don't hardcode the preferred size of the panel. Use a layout manager on the panel and the layout will dynamically determine the preferred size of the panel. The scrollbars will then work automatically.

Answer (score -2):

Solved: by setting the width of panel_12 bigger than the width of scroll_12..

I would like to see if anyone else has to propose another solution...

thanks again

Comment: This is best as part of the question (given it is a poor solution and you request better). Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37398283/edit) with new information.

Comment: i dont know how to edit my answer as part of the question.. why this is wrong?

Comment: *"dont know how to edit my answer as part of the question."* Click the LINK in my comment.. *"why this is wrong?"* Post the MCVE I suggested almost 24 hours ago, and I'll explain further.